# How to open a angularJS modal when the url has a queryString

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to develop a web site. I want to open a $uiModal when the url has a querystring. If the query string is not there then no modal is oepn. The code is:

```
myApp.controller('jobObjectiveController', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', 'EmployeeObjectiveService', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, EmployeeObjectiveService, $routeParams) {

$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.AddButton = 'Save';
    $scope.isProcessing = false;
    $scope.UpdateButton = 'Update';
}

var id = $routeParams.id;


var items = [];
for (i = 0; i <10; i++) {
    items[i] = i;
}
$scope.test = items;

$scope.Objective = {
    Title: '',
    KPI: '',
    Target: '',
    Weight: '',
    Note:''
}

$scope.init();

//Column Selection 
EmployeeObjectiveService.GetObjectiveColumnList().then(function (response) { $scope.ColumnList = response.data });
EmployeeObjectiveService.GetObjectiveSeletedColumnList().then(function (response) { $scope.SelectedColumn = response.data });
EmployeeObjectiveService.GetObjectiveSeletCol().then(function (response) { $scope.selectCol = response.data});

//Change Events for Multiple dropdown
$scope.changeEvents = {
    onItemSelect: function (item) {
        changeColumnViewShow(item);
    },
    onItemDeselect: function (item) {
        changeColumnViewShow(item);
    }
};

function changeColumnViewShow(item) {
    if (item.id == 1) {
        $scope.selectCol.Code = !$scope.selectCol.Code;
    } else if (item.id == 2) {
        $scope.selectCol.Title = !$scope.selectCol.Title;
    } else if (item.id == 3) {
        $scope.selectCol.KPI = !$scope.selectCol.KPI;
    } else if (item.id == 4) {
        $scope.selectCol.Target = !$scope.selectCol.Target;
    } else if (item.id == 5) {
        $scope.selectCol.Weight = !$scope.selectCol.Weight;
    } else if (item.id == 6) {
        $scope.selectCol.Note = !$scope.selectCol.Note;
    } else if (item.id == 7) {
        $scope.selectCol.Status = !$scope.selectCol.Status;
    }
}

//Multiple Dropsown Config
$scope.dropConfig = {
    scrollable: true,
    scrollableHeight: '200px',
    showCheckAll: false,
    showUncheckAll: false
}

//Group by Pending and Approve
EmployeeObjectiveService.getGroupItem().then(function (response) { $scope.GroupBy = response.data });

//Open Modal for Add Objective
$scope.addObjective = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/View/Modal View/addObejective.html',
        controller:'jobObjectiveController',
        scope: $scope,
        size: 'lg'
    });
}

//Open Modal for View Objective
$scope.viewObjective = function (data) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/View/Modal View/ObejectiveModal.html',
        controller: 'jobObjectiveController',
        scope: $scope,
        size: 'lg',
    });
}

//Open Modal for Update Objective
$scope.updateObjective = function (data) {
    $scope.Object = {
        Title: 'xgdsg',
        KPI: 'sgsg',
        Target: 'sgsg',
        Weight: 'sgsgggggg',
        Note: data
    }
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/View/Modal View/updateObejectiveModal.html',
        controller: 'jobObjectiveController',
        scope: $scope,
        size: 'lg'
    });
}


//Add the Objective
$scope.AddObjective = function (data) {
    $scope.AddButton = 'Saving...';
    $scope.isProcessing = true;
    if (!data) {
        alert("Submitting...");
        $scope.init();
    }else
        $scope.init();

}

//Update Objective
$scope.UpdateObjective = function (data) {
    $scope.UpdateButton = 'Updating...';
    $scope.isProcessing = true;
    if (!data) {
        alert("Submitting...");
        $scope.init();
    } else
        $scope.init();

}

if (id != null) {
    $scope.viewObjective(id);
}
```

When i run the code with query string then show these errors

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at m.$scope.getButtonText (angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js:1)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.min.js:1001), <anonymous>:4:230)
at angular.min.js:534
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:600)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:610)
at l (angular.min.js:397)
at J (angular.min.js:417)
at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular.min.js:420)
```

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? If so, please mark an answer as accepted, otherwise leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to the url changes using and check there is a querystring to open the modal:

`$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(args){})`

Answer (score 0):

See if you are using route params then that is correct that you will get id for other wise if you are sending query string parameters then use

```
// given URL http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}

// set foo to 'yipee'
$location.search('foo', 'yipee');
// $location.search() => {foo: 'yipee', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

This way you can get that and keep condition on init method so that if parameter id is there then you can call open method of modal

refer [Angular $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)